# Assigning a scope value in angular template from a dynamic value in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am having an issue with using a value in a ng-repeat and passing that value to a service (http) promise and then updating a table row with the response from the service.

My code is like this

template:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Course Name</th>
                        <th>Current Section</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="course in courses" ng-init="set_current_section(course.course_id)">
                        <td>{{course.course_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{current_course}}</td>
                     </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Then my controller

```
$scope.set_current_section = function(course_id) {
    staff_service.get_start_section(course_id).then(function(result){

        $scope.current_course = result;
    })
}
```

and the service

```
this.get_start_section = function(course_id) {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.get('http://' + remoteServer + '/api/course_get_start_section/' + $sessionStorage.user_id + '/' + course_id)
        .success(function(response){ deferred.resolve(response); })
        .error(function(){ console.log('error getting start section'); })

    return deferred.promise;

}; // close create_new_section
```

I can console.log the value returned from the service and it is correct. But the scope value current_section is the same for all the lines in the table.

My question is, how to set a scope value for a dynamic table row and not have the same scope name and result in them all getting the last value?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change your ng-init to this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="course in courses">
    <td>{{course.course_name}}</td>
    <td ng-init="current_course = set_current_section(course.course_id)">{{current_course}}</td>
</tr>
```

You have been setting current_course on the main $scope which is shared by everything in the ng-repeat. that's why it's not working.

Comment: Hi Mathew, thanks for the reply. When I do that the {{current_course}} is blank. Maybe something to do with the service promise?